# how to test for partial continuity of a multivariable function. Also, can a partial derivative of a function be $\infty$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

So, let there be a scalar function $f(x,y)$. We know that the partial derivatives exist for every $(x,y)$. In the following example we know that the function is not continuous:
$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 
  \dfrac{2xy}{x^2+y^2} &\text{if } (x,y) \neq (0,0), \\[2pt] 
  0 &\text{if } (x,y)=(0,0).
\end{cases}
$$

How can we test for example if the partial derivative of this function with respect to $x$ is continuous?

And generally on any function how is this tested?

If we assume that a partial derivative on a multivariable function exists, can it be $\infty$?
Are there any repercussion for this statement, if true?

Comment: If it were continuous, you would have that the relation $(x_n,y_n) \to (x,y)$ implies $f(x_n,y_n) \to f(x,y)$ for every $(x,y)$ and every sequence converging to this point. Consider the origin and sequences like $x_n=y_n=1/n.$

Answer (score 0):

As $f(x,0)=0$ $${\partial f\over \partial x}(0,0)={d\over dx}f(x,0)\mid_{x=0}=0$$  For $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ we get $${\partial f\over \partial x}(x,y)= {\partial \over dx} {2xy\over x^2+y^2}=2{y^3-x^2y\over (x^2+y^2)^2}$$ Thus
$${\partial f\over \partial x}(x,y)=\begin{cases} 0 & x=y=0\\ 2{y(y^2-x^2)\over (x^2+y^2)^2} & (x,y)\neq (0,0) \end{cases}$$
Thus ${\partial f\over \partial x}$ is continuous at every point $(x,y)\neq (0,0).$ But it is not continuous at $(0,0).$ Indeed for  for $a>0$ and $y\neq 0$ we get $${\partial f\over \partial x}(ay,y)={2\over y}{1-a^2\over (1+a^2)^2}$$ Thus for $a=2$ there holds $$\lim_{y\to 0^-}{\partial f\over \partial x}(ay,y)=\infty $$ Hence ${\partial f\over \partial x}$ is not continuous at $(0,0).$